# Validar columna Datatable jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datatable

Hola estoy tratando de validar una columna de mi tabla pero  no se como validar pero con los detalle de otra columna 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que deseo es que cuando  la data es false valide otro campo que es imagen

Comment: Buenas, podrías añadir tu código en vez de una imagen?

Answer (score 0):

[En la funcción de render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render); el parametro de data tiene el valor que le asignas en columns.Para utilizar el resto de las propiedades del registro lo puedes tomar desde el parametro row.

```
if(row.Imagen === ""){
  ....
}
```

Comment: gracias me ayudo mucho